# RecycleView layout manager list items are taking the whole screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-virtual-device

So i just made this simple fragment that contains a RecycleView. The recycle view has a custom made relative layout with two TextViews and a CheckBox. The problem is that a single list item takes up the whole AVD seceen's space and the listener I set for the list item is not working.

[here is a screenshot of the AVD screen (I am using android studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lspLX.png)

[And when scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrvoL.png)

The XML layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        tools:text="Crime Title"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
        android:padding="4dp"
        tools:text="Crime date"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Fragment java code:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment
{
    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    private CrimeAdabter mCrimeAdabter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);
        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        updateUI();
        return v;
    }

    private void updateUI()
    {
        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();
        mCrimeAdabter = new CrimeAdabter(crimes);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCrimeAdabter);
    }


}
```

The ViewHolder java code:

```
private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDateTextView;
    private CheckBox mCrimeSolvedCheckBox;
    private Crime mCrime;

    public CrimeHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_title_text_view);
        mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_date_text_view);
        mCrimeSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_solved_check_box);
    }

    public void bindCrime(Crime crime)
    {
        mCrime = crime;
        mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mCrimeSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),CrimeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And the Adapter java code:

```
private class CrimeAdabter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder>
{
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    public CrimeAdabter(List<Crime> crimes)
    {
        mCrimes = crimes;
    }

    @Override
    public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false);

        return new CrimeHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
        holder.bindCrime(crime);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mCrimes.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: change relative height to wrap_content

Comment: change your relativeLayout height android:layout_height="match_parent" to wrap_content

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because your root RelativeLayout's height is set to **match_parent**. Make it wrap_content or specific height.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But do you know why the listener isnt working?

Comment: @omerabbas because you don't set it to the view :)

Comment: Thanks mate I feel like a total idiot for forgetting that :(