# In recyclerView, it seems like one cardView takes whole list view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I got problem like below.

I have 3 cardView, but I only can see one of them at first. Like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZhFx.jpg)

If I scroll down a little, I can see an another.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SvFr.jpg)

A little bit more,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yknkd.jpg)

And finally,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5WN2.jpg)

It seems like there is a small box like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v2xz.jpg)

I want the cardView to be listed with a proper margin.
In my stupid thinking, I made mistakes in RecyclerView

This is my fragment_item_list_view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_item_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.androidaudiorecorder.ItemFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item"/>
```

This is my classes from RecyclerViewAdapter

```
    public RecordingsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);

    mContext = parent.getContext();

    return new RecordingsViewHolder(itemView);
}


public static class RecordingsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView vName;
    protected TextView vLength;
    protected TextView vDateAdded;
    protected View cardView;

    public RecordingsViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        vName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_name_text);
        vLength = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_length_text);
        vDateAdded = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_date_added_text);
        cardView = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_item);
    }
}
```

This is my classes from ItemFragment

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {

private ItemRecyclerViewAdapter mItemRecyclerViewAdapter;

// TODO: Customize parameter argument names
private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
// TODO: Customize parameters
private int mColumnCount = 1;

private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ItemFragment() {
}

// TODO: Customize parameter initialization
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static ItemFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
    ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        observer.startWatching();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //newest to oldest order
    llm.setReverseLayout(true);
    llm.setStackFromEnd(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mItemRecyclerViewAdapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), llm);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mItemRecyclerViewAdapter);
    return v;
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

p.s. I've tried to change layout_height to "match parent" already, but it affected only to the size of the fragment..

Thank you for reading it!
I will be very happy if you give me a hand!

Edit : this is my fragment_item.xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:transitionName="open_mediaplayer"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/file_name_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="file_name"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/file_length_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/file_date_added_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="mmm dd yyyy - hh:mm a"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why is your recycler view height wrap_content? can you also show R.layout.fragment_item?

Comment: In your `R.layout.fragment_item` the parent view must be having height as `fill_parent` / `match_parent`. Change that to `wrap_content`.

Comment: is seems there is some margin between items in fragment_item

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RecycleView layout manager list items are taking the whole screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253750/recycleview-layout-manager-list-items-are-taking-the-whole-screen)

Comment: Thanks for giving answers, but it is still same. I uploaded my fragment_view.xml code. Please check it out!

Answer (score 3):

Change the item's width to "match_parent" and the height to "wrap_content"